# jQuery popup bar - how to hide by default?

Tags: jquery, html, popup, hide

I followed this tutorial to create a popup bar (similar to the one at the top of this site):

http://spyrestudios.com/how-to-create-a-cute-popup-bar-with-html5-css3-and-jquery/

I'm new to jQuery so I'm wondering if it is possible to have the bar hidden by default and only displayed when the user clicks on the 'show' button.

popup.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    


$('.showpop').hide();
$('#popup').show('bounce', { times:1 }, 300);


$('.hide').click(function(){
    $('#popup').slideUp();
    $('span.showpop').fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
});


$('a.showpoplink').click(function(){
    $('#popup').show('bounce', { times:1 }, 300);
    $('.showpop').hide();
    return false;
});
});
```

Sorry if its dead obvious! As I said I've just started learning this, been playing about with it but with no results.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
$('.showpop').hide();
$('#popup').show('bounce', { times:1 }, 300);
```

try

```
$('#popup').hide();
$('.showpop').show('bounce', { times:1 }, 300);
```

(havnt tested but should work)

Comment: simple if it works the exact opposite to what you require, swap it around :)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing this line:

```
$('#popup').show('bounce', { times:1 }, 300);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I removed the line but unfortunatly it is still showing every time the page is refreshed. I can provide a link to the page it's being used on if it may help?

Comment: @user1039878 yes, provide a link

Answer (score 1):

Simply comment out the second line -- that's the code that shows the bar when the page has loaded:

`// $('#popup').show('bounce', { times:1 }, 300);`

Comment: I'm afraid it doesnt seem to make a difference other than to stop the little bounce animation. It still displays by default every time the page is refreshed :(

Answer (score 0):

Change the bar so that its display is none. That way it is hidden when the page loads and you don't have to hide it with JavaScript on first load. Then you can show it only on user clicks.